# Visual Studio 2015 UnitTesting namespace missing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2015. I'm trying to create several unit tests within a test class but I can't find the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting namespace. I've tried adding a reference to it but it doesn't show up in any of the lists. Is there some new way to accomplish this? I have a Visual Studio 2013 project that is able to find this namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding a reference to **Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework**?

Comment: Yup, this has stumped me in the past too

Comment: I did a search for "Microsoft.Visual" studio after opening the Add Reference menu. I was able to locate the UnitTestFramework from there. That fixed the issue.